# Switching the divs via script in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have the following code to switch between 2 divs:

```
<script>
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2)
{
   d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
   d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
   if( d2.style.display == "none" )
   {
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "block";
   }
   else
   {
      d1.style.display = "block";
      d2.style.display = "none";
   }
}

var divs = [ "zdroj1", "zdroj2" ];
function toggle(layer) {
    var d
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
        d = document.getElementById(divs[i]);
        d.style.display = 'none';
    }
    d = document.getElementById(layer);
    d.style.display = '';
}
</script>
```

And the HTML part:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="btn" style="text-align: center;"><a href="javascript:toggle('zdroj1')" ><b>VIDEO 1</b></a></div></td>
<td class="btn" style="text-align: center;"><a href="javascript:toggle('zdroj2')" ><b>VIDEO 2</b></a></div></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>  

<div id="zdroj1">
VIDEO CODE 1</div>

<div id="zdroj2" style="display:none;">
VIDEO CODE 2</div>
```

How can I add more divs and show only that one which link is clicked? I think that there must be more if functions in the script but I am not sure, because I am a newbie in this part of coding. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Based on your needs to have a dynamic amount of divs/buttons on each page see the code below. Instead of manually creating the click eventListener you need to get an array(-ish) of the buttons based on a common class name (querySelector could also be used for this) and add the event listener to each. The buttons should be created with a data-attribute (or other identifier) that corresponds to one of the divs you want to toggle.

Inside the function that is called you can loop through all your msg divs, hide them all and unhide the one that matches the data-attribute of the button that was clicked. This method allows you to have any number of buttons and divs as long as each button has a matching div for it to toggle.

```js
// Find all the buttons and divs that have the common className for each
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button')
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('msg')

function toggle() {
    // Loop through the divs and hide them all
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
     divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    // Show the div whose id matches the data-message attribute of the button that was clicked
    document.getElementById(this.dataset.message).style.display = 'block';
}

// Add a click listener to each button to run the toggle function
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', toggle, false)
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  
   <tr>
    <!-- Add a common class to all buttons and a data-message attribute to each button
         that corresponds to the id of the div it will toggle on-->
   <td class="btn"><button class="button" data-message="msg1">VIDEO 1</button></td>
   <td class="btn"><button class="button" data-message="msg2">VIDEO 2</button></td>
   <td class="btn"><button class="button" data-message="msg3">VIDEO 3</button></td>
   <td class="btn"><button class="button" data-message="msg4">VIDEO 3</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

  <!-- Add a common class to all divs that will be toggled -->
<div class="msg" id="msg1">
 VIDEO CODE 1
</div>

<div class="msg" id="msg2" style="display:none;">
 VIDEO CODE 2
</div>

<div class="msg" id="msg3" style="display:none;">
 VIDEO CODE 3
</div>

<div class="msg" id="msg4" style="display:none;">
 VIDEO CODE 4
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, it works this way which you showed me, thanks! Just one problem occurred, when I have changed the html part just for 2 divs, for example:
<div id="msg1">
 VIDEO CODE 1
</div>

<div id="msg2" style="display:none;">
 VIDEO CODE 2
</div>

After click are hidden all divs. Do you think that there is a way to keep the same script code with more html pages with different number of divs?

Comment: @Jan I updated my answer to a more dynamic approach, hope that helps.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark the answer correct if it solved your problem.